# How to run only one test method via ant in Hybris

Tags: testing, ant, sap-commerce-cloud

I have test class `MyTest`:

```
package com.my.package;
...
@IntegrationTest
public class MyTest extends ServicelayerTest {
    @Test
    public myTest1() {...}

    @Test
    public myTest2() {...}
}
```

I only need to run the `myTest1()` test via ant.

To run all integration tests from the class, I can use

`ant integrationtests -Dtestclasses.packages='com.my.package.MyTest'`

How to run only one `myTest1()` ? Maybe I can use something like

`ant integrationtests -Dtestclasses.packages='com.my.package.MyTest#myTest1()'`  ?

Comment: it can be done via commenting annotation @test but I don't think so there is any dynamic way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no filter that lets you run JUnit by method name.

Check the Filters documentation on what is supported: https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/f7f454a4f5254944a366db9bdf129be6.html